# how can i determine the model of dyno brand BMX i have

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

I have a dyno vfr 3d dropout flat oval bike.

How can I find out what it is?

The serial number is S9ET18105.

Comment: Without photos we won't be able to even guess. We're not the manufacturer, so we don't have the list of serial numbers. Also, capital letters would help make your question readable, and a description of what research you've already done.

Answer (score 3):

The Bike you have is a GT VFR BMX bike designed by Dyno, and made of 1020 high tensile steel.

These were made for a number of years.

One model, 1997, is like this:

[image]

[image]

Your answer is literally in your question.